# Ubuntu won't get further than plain screen after booting

Tags: installation, wubi

I downloaded version 12.04 and have tried to boot it using the Wubi. It opens a plain screen with the word Ubuntu and five dots under it which change colour a couple of times. Then nothing. All I can do is restart - but the same happens.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 1300 with Windows XP also on it. I've looked at other similar problems which may be due to the same cause but have no idea how to use command prompts etc to attempt a fix. Should I give up on Ubuntu?

Comment: You can press `Esc` when the purple screen appears to view the logs and update your question with the error being presented! _ps: never give up on Ubuntu :)_

Answer (score 0):

I've seen alot of issues with Dells and Ubuntu, and in fact anything but windows.

## What I would do

1. Acquire live CD/USB
2. Boot into Ubuntu (try ubuntu)
3. Start "gparted"
4. review drive table to see if anything weird is present. Perhaps a seperate boot partition.

This might help you explain the weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem at the purple screen showing the Ubuntu logo is usually related to your graphics adapter and the driver being used by Ubuntu.

The best solution is to access your Ubuntu installation using [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode) and install the most recent driver package:

1. To enter Recovery Mode, hold <kbd>ESQ</kbd> when the `Grub loading...` message appears so the GRUB menu is displayed.
2. Choose the `Ubuntu, kernel xxx... (recovery mode)` option.
3. Choose to mount the disk as read/write, and select:

   > Drop to root shell prompt with networking
4. After all the load process finish, type the following commands (one at a time):

   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get upgrade
   >
   > sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
   >
   > reboot

If all went well, you should be able to pass the purple screen and get to your desktop.

---

**Related documentation:**

[Configuring the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 900-950 for Linux    [Linux Wiki Guides]](http://www.linwik.com/wiki/configuring+the+intel+graphics+media+accelerator+900-950+for+linux)

[Dell™ Inspiron™ 1300/B120/B130  Service Manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/SYSTEMS/ins1300/en/sm/index.htm)

[Dell Inspiron 1300 Review (pics, specs)](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=2738) *(points out the graphics card used)*

[UbuntuUpdates.org - Package "xserver-xorg-video-intel"](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu-x-swat/precise/main/base/xserver-xorg-video-intel)